# Database table design approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a question about proper table design. Imagine the situation:

You have two entities in the table (Company and Actor).
Actor could have several types (i.e. Shop, PoS, Individual etc.)

- The relation between entities is many-to-many because one Actor can be assigned to multiple Companies and vice-versa (one Company can have multiple Actors)
- To outline this relation, I can create a linking table called 'C2A' for instance. So, we'll end up with the structure like this:

  | Company1 | Actor1(Shop)

  | Company1 | Actor2(PoS)

  | Company2 | Actor1(PoS)

  etc.
- This approach works just fine until requirement changes. Now we need to have a possibility to assign Actor to an Actor to build another sort of hierarchy, i.e. one Actor (Shop) might have multiple other Actors (PoS's) assigned to it and all this belong to a certain company. So, we'll end up with the structure like this:

  | Company1 | Actor1(Shop) | NULL

  | NULL     | Actor1(Shop) | Actor1(PoS)

  | NULL     | Actor1(Shop) | Actor2(PoS)

  etc.

I need to be able to express relations (between Company (C) and Actor(A)) like this: C - A - A; A - C - A; A - A - C

Having two similar fields in one table is not the best idea. How are the relationships like this normally designed?

Comment: I don't know what Shops and PoSs are, but it appears that they should be in a separate table with a many to may relationship with Actor.

Comment: Actually, the first relationship is only one to many. There's only 1 Actor with Many companies that they can work for. Your Actor table has to be unique with each ID and SSN and Name. Link the ID of each Actor to the Company that has its own Unique ID. Where you lost me is this: "Now we need to have a possibility to assign Actor to an Actor to build another sort of hierarchy". Can you explain this?

Comment: make one linking table for company to actor and another linking table actor to actor.  Why put them in the same table -- they are different.

Comment: @DanBracuk, PoS is a point of sale (or distribution point). One company may interact with the shop directly of with PoS, or with the Shop that is connected to may PoSs. Shops and distribution points do not belong to this particular company, so, it means many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Isaiah3015, Actor is not a physical person, it's an entity (like Shop, or PoS, i.e. the entity has a certain type I enumerated above). Actor to Actor assignment means that one Shop may have multiple distribution points (PoSs) and related to a Company that interacts with it. I need to be able to show this hierarchy.

Comment: @Hogan, it makes perfect sense, I think this is the right approach, I'm just worried about select statement perofrmance

Comment: Worry not -- sql is designed to do joins -- a query with 5 to 10 joins is normal, if your indexes are well designed performance should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate tables for entities Company and Actors.

```
Company( Id (PK), Name)
Actor(Id (PK), Name)
```

Now, if you are sure about many-many. You can go ahead with creating a separate table for this.

```
CompanyActorMap( MapId (PK), CompanyId (FK), ActorId (FK))
```

For Actor Heirarchy, use a separate table as it has nothing to do with how the hierarchy is related to the company, its about how the Actors are related to each other. Best approach for multiple level infinite hierarchy is to create a new table with two columns for Actor Id as Foreign Key

```
ActorHierarchy( HierarchyId (PK), ChildActorId (FK), ParentActorId(FK))
```

For an Actor that has no parent in hierarchy, there can be an entry in CompanyActorMap table denoting the head of hierarchy and the remaining chain can be derived from the ActorHierarchy table by checking the PArentActorId column and its childActorId.

This is obviously a rough draft. Hope this helps.

Comment: Always my pleasure